# How to limit ListView height on click of a button

Tags: android, listview, height

I have created a order card that have one listview. Initially I have displayed only 2 items of listview but onClick of arrow button I want to show full listview and after that if I click arrow again I want to show only 2 items . I am able to show full listview but after that not able to minimize it height to 100 dp again that I have in xml file earlier.

> Below is my code where I have button and maintain another adapter height for it:-

```
       Boolean isexpand= false

    viewHolder.showhide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if(isexpand == true)
        {
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(viewHolder.menulist);
        }

        else

        {
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(100);
        }


        }
```

And for listview I am setting another adapter i.e. menuadapter :

```
 viewHolder.listview.setAdapter(new MenuAdapterForAll(mContext,menuModels));
            setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(viewHolder.listview);
```

// code for that menu adapter

```
   public class MenuAdapterForAll extends BaseAdapter
     {

ArrayList<MenuItemModel> dataSet1;
Context mContextnew;
Typeface face, face1;




// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image_menu_type;
    TextView menu_item_name;
    TextView menu_item_price;
    TextView menu_item_qty;
    CheckBox cbmenu;
}


public MenuAdapterForAll(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<MenuItemModel> menuModels) {
    this.dataSet1=menuModels;
    this.mContextnew=applicationContext;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}

private int lastPosition = -1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View vv, ViewGroup parent) {

    // View vv= LayoutInflater.from(mContextnew).inflate(R.layout.adapter_listview_menuitems, null, false);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    final View result;
    final MenuItemModel data=dataSet1.get(position);

    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContextnew.getAssets(), "fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf");
    face1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContextnew.getAssets(), "fonts/Rupee_Foradian_2.ttf");



    if (vv == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContextnew);
        vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_listview_menuitems, parent, false);

        viewHolder.menu_item_name=(TextView)vv.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_name);
        viewHolder.menu_item_price=(TextView)vv.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_price);
        viewHolder.menu_item_qty=(TextView)vv.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_qty);
        viewHolder.image_menu_type =(ImageView) vv.findViewById(R.id.image_menu_type);
        viewHolder.cbmenu =(CheckBox) vv.findViewById(R.id.cbmenu);


        result=vv;
        vv.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
```

** I am not able to set height to 100 dp again in else part.**

Unable to track what might be the issue, any help would be really very valuable.

--Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried layout params?

Comment: I tried but getting error. Can you please help me its really urgent @Rasi

Comment: Simple way is to have two different list. one will have only two items and second will have all items. On click you can change the list and refresh adapter by calling notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: I have done this but I also have checkbox before each listitem and its value reflecet  after refreshing. So if I have 2 listview and if i check one checkbox of a listview and it will not be reflected on another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getCount`of listview adapter class method instead of setting the height

```
public int getCount() {
    return noOfRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(list.size() > 2 && !isexpand){
       return 2;
    }
    else
    {
       return list.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean is that I have button in one adapter and list in another adapter. How can I do this.

Comment: @MukeshMishra, can you please add some code for both adapter, where you have tried to set the height ?\

Comment: @MukeshMishra, What is in `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren` method?

Comment: In it I have coded to set height according to child size in list @Mayur

Comment: @MukeshMishra, Where you have done set Height? for the child? in `getview()` ? or some where else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133959/discussion-between-mukesh-mishra-and-mayur-raval).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
viewHolder.showhide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

and in getCount method of adapter:

```
  public int getCount() {
if(!isexpand)
return 2;
else return yourList.size()  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think for checkbox problem solve with adding his two methods:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}
```